# SonarQube: Check if a project with the same key already exists while first analysis/build

Tags: maven, jenkins, sonarqube

I am building my projects with Jenkins and analyze them with SonarQube.

The problem I am trying to fix without writting my own Plugin is the following:

- 1.) Jenkins starts a build of a new project (never built or analyzed an SonarQube before)
- 2.) SonarQube analysis is triggered
- 3.) SonarQube shell check if a project with the same key already exists
- 4a.) If it already exists: Abort analysis and throw error message
- 4b.) If it not exist: Continue the analysis as a normal analysis

Or in other words: If a Project is analyzed for the first time, I want SonarQube to make sure that there is no other project already existing with the same key this new project uses. The goal is to avoid overwritting existing projects by a complete other project
If a project has been already analyized and the new analysis would be a like "updating the old results" i don't want any error message to show up.

Can i simply install a plugin? Must i change things within the pom.xml? Is there a way? And if yes: how does it work?

(I know the possibility to get the buildnumber of the last successful build in Jenkins. And if it would be greater or equal 1 there would be no reason for my check anymore. If it's not: i need my check)

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I don't think it works that way. How should SonarQube be able to decide if it's a new project or just another analysis of an existing one? That's what the key (I would call it ID) is for. If it's a new project, just give it a non existing ID.

Comment: maybe i was unclear: if i was i'm sorry for that.

I can check via Jenkins if the project is new or already analyzed for a few times, but...

... I want to know: is there a way to check SonarQube if it already contains a project with the same key (groupId:artifactId) as the project that is now going to be analyzed? And if yes: how can i access this point? :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `/api/resources?resource=project-key` Web Service from a script to check if the given project key already exists (if not, the WS will answer with a 404).

However, as @andre-stannek said: in the end it is your responsibility to make sure that 2 projects don't use the same key. There is no way for SQ to know if the analyzed project is an update of an existing project or not.

Comment: Great, thanks for your answer!
The company i am working for is very big. So here are working many developers on over 200 projects. So we try to work out a way to check if a project key already exists. In the end you are right: we can't make sure if its an update or a new project, but we can try to. In addition: i am just executing the tasks that are given to me.
But thanks for your answer anyway. You were a great help :)

Comment: Thanks. Use `/api/components/show?key=xxx` after version `5.4`.